# Angular 2 Search

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to use a search box to filter a list of items using Angular 2 but when I type stuff into the search box it never fires the search method on the service. I know I'm probably missing something simple but any help would be much appreciated.

**company.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { CompanyModel } from './company';
import { CompaniesModel } from './company';

@Injectable()
export class CompanyService {

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  search(term: string): Observable<CompaniesModel> {
      console.log('search service', term);
      return this.http
          .get('/api/Company/Search/?search=' + term)
          .map((r: Response) => r.json().data as CompaniesModel);
  }
}
```

**companies.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { CompanyModel } from './company';
import { CompaniesModel } from './company';
import { CompanyService } from './company.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'companies-list',
  templateUrl: 'companies.component.html'
})
export class CompaniesComponent implements OnInit {
    companiesModel: Observable<CompaniesModel>;
    private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(
      private companyService: CompanyService,
    private router: Router) { }

  search(term: string): void {
      this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.companiesModel = this.searchTerms
          .debounceTime(300) 
          .distinctUntilChanged()
          .switchMap(term => this.companyService.search(term));

  }

  gotoDetail(company: CompanyModel): void {
      let link = ['/company', company.Id];
      this.router.navigate(link);
  }
}
```

**companies.component.html**

```
<h2>Companies</h2>
<div>
    <label>Search: </label>
    <input #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" />
</div>
<div>
    <button (click)="create()">
        Add
    </button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="companiesModel" class="grid grid-pad">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let company of companiesModel.Companies | async" (click)="gotoDetail(company)">
            <div>
                <h4>{{company.Name}}</h4>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all?

Comment: Nope, no errors. I tried putting a console.log in the component search method and the service search method. Only the component search method logs anything to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never subscribing on the subject `searchTerms`. If you do not subscribe, the operators you've layed out will never be executed.

```
this.searchTerms
      .debounceTime(300) 
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.companyService.search(term))
      .subscribe((val) => //do something with the result here);
```

Example Jsbin. Add the subscribe statement to see the console logs.
http://jsbin.com/zijuvet/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Ok, when I put the subscribe I do get it to hit the service's search method but it never actually does the http.get within that method. No errors like a 404 either.

Comment: Hmm, that's something the switchMap should do for you under the covers. It shoud subscribe to the result of the `companyService.search`. 
Your url does look a little weird though:  .get('/api/Company/Search/?search=' + term). Shouldn't this be get('http://localhost:8080/api/...) or something similar.

Comment: Could you try and return the following from your service. return Observable.of(["a", "b", "c"]). and see if your component gets that vlaue

Comment: I modified the service's search to return an object that I created within the method:

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize enter posted....

 
I modified the service's search to return an object that I created within the method and added a console log in there to log out the newly created object and that console.log shows the object correctly. However, my component.ts/component.html don't reflect the object being returned in the view. Do I have something wired up wrong on the front-end?

Comment: Are you returning an object or an observable with an object? Switchmap expects an observable to be returned. So if you use 'return Observable.of(["a", "b", "c"])' and than you have the subscribe method as in my answer with as body ((val) => console.log(val)) the array should be logged out.

Comment: Sorry, Observable.of(object).

Comment: Well... it appears my issue was that my list of companies was a property on companiesModel. When I changed the method to just return an array of companies from the service it worked fine.

Comment: That's mean you don't actually need the method of subscribe() to get your result set, since I didn't see a subscribe is mentioned in the [Official Angular 2 Tutorial, 'Tour of Heroes'](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#herosearchcomponent) ? correct?

Comment: Using the async pipe, you are actually subscribing. The pipe does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the same using below code as well

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="queryString" id="search" placeholder="Search to type">
```

Pipe

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'FilterPipe',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, input: string) {
        if (input) {
            input = input.toLowerCase();
            return value.filter(function (el: any) {
                return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
            })
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

You can modify the code as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 searching without any custom pipes

```
<table>
 <thead>...</thead>
 <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let part of filterParts let i=index"></tr>
</tboby>
```

//code in component.ts file

```
 Partsfiltering(inputName){
       this.filterParts = [];
      if(inputName != ""){
            this.parts.forEach(element => {         
       if(element.partNumber.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputName.toUpperCase())>=0){
                  this.filterParts.push(element);
               }
            });
      }else{
         this.filterParts = this.parts;
      }
     }
```